# Performing an action when _statusItem is clicked, with a NSMenu and the window not in focus seems impossible

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nsapplication

There are similar questions on SO but this have a twist.

I need to trigger an action when the user clicks on my app icon sitting on the menu bar. The action is to bring its window to the front, or in other words,

```
  [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Normally I would do this:

```
[_statusItem setTarget:self];
[_statusItem setAction:@selector(bringToFront:)];
```

but this `_statusItem` has a `NSMenu`.

If I disable the menu, `bringToFront:` is triggered.

So I thought, I will implement `NSMenuDelegate` method `menuWillOpen`.

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu {
  [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

But there is a problem. This will work if the app window is the one selected, but suppose the app is running and I select safari. Then, my app's window is not in focus anymore, is behind 2000 Safari windows. Now I click on my app's icon on the menu bar and `menuWillOpen` will not be triggered.

If I want to bring the window to focus by clicking on the app's icon on the menu bar, having to bring the window to focus to make it work does not make sense.

Comment: `NSApplication` notifications are posted in response to your app gaining/resigning active status. Have you tried enabling/disabling your status item's menu in response to these?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Do what part? Read the `NSApplication` documentation for details of the notifications.

Comment: I am not seeing how it can help. I want to make the app active by clicking on the menu, not selecting an item from it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You wrote "If I disable the menu, bringToFront: is triggered" so I wondered whether you'd tried disabling it when your app resigned active status...

Comment: Ah, I see. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Brilliant! Please make your comment an answer, so I can accept! THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSApplication` notifications are posted in response to your app gaining/resigning active status. Handle these notifications and enable/disable your status item's menu so that your action gets invoked when your app is in the background.